# Getting issues while fetching records based on UTC date string by passing java date formatted on specific timezone

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker and using format as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ` the text input I am storing as it is in database column.

I have to store it as string only. While fetching records I am passing `fromdate` and `toDate` which are for applications timezone (other than client machine). We set timezone through application as well.

For MySQL query I am doing date comparison using:

```
str_to_date(column_name,'%Y-%m-%dT%T')
```

This gives an issue in fetching records. Any suggestions?

My problem is when I am not sure whether I am right about datetimepicker format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to store it as string only.

Stop.  Right there.  There are very few reasons why you would really want to store your dates and timestamps in a MySQL database as pure text.  Instead, you should be using a date column, which would alleviate your need to call `STR_TO_DATE` in the first place.

With regard to your call to `STR_TO_DATE`, I think your format mask should be this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(column_name, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ')
```

This appears to be working in the demo below.

### Demo